# Error trying to create login system

Tags: php

I've been trying to create a login system in PHP.
I've managed to successfully to connect the database but I'm got a problem saying

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp1\htdocs\login\check.php on line 23
>   Wrong username or password are wrong
>   Notice: Undefined property: mysqli::$close in C:\xampp1\htdocs\login\check.php on line 36

My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="check.php" >
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Username</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>password</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="password"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
ob_start();
$username= $_POST['username'];
$password= $_POST['password'];

$servername= "localhost";
$username= "root";
$password = "";
$dbname="login";

$conn= mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

if (!$conn){
    die("Not connected". mysqli_connect_error);
}else{
    echo "connection sucessful";

}

$sql= "select * from details where $username=username and $password=password";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);



if ($count == 1){
    header("location:sucess.php");
}else{
    echo "Wrong username or password are wrong";


}
$conn->close;
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Mixing `mysqli and mysql` in your code

Comment: Look at that query again

Comment: username='$username' is what you are looking for and please read up on PDO

Comment: far too many things wrong with this question/code.

Answer (score 0):

try this sql:

```
$sql= "select * from details where username='{$username}' and password='{$password}'";
```

Comment: use column='value' or column LIKE 'value'

Answer (score 0):

Correction 1: `$username=username` has to be `username=$username`

Correction 2:

```
$sql= "select * from details where $username=username and $password=password";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Has to be: [I would suggest you using prepared statements]

```
$user_name = $username;
$pwd = $password;


$query = $conn->prepare("select * from details where username = ? and password = ?");

$query->bind_param("ss",$user_name,$pwd);

if (!$query->execute())
{
    echo $conn->error;
}

$row_cnt = $query->num_rows;
```